# Why is this Dart code so slow compared to java's implementation?

Tags: dart, dart-io

The dart codes as follows is extremely slow compared to java's implementation.

```
//test.dart
import 'dart:io';
void main(){
for(int i = 0; i < 1 << 25;i++){
   stdout.write(i); // or directly print(i);
 }
  stdout.close();
}
```

java version:

```
//Test.java
import java.io.*;
public class Test{
public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        for(int i = 0;i < 1 << 25; i++){
            out.print(i);
        }
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
  }
}
```

$ time java Test > /dev/null

```
real    0m6.421s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.031s
```

$ time dart Test.dart > /dev/null

```
real    0m51.978s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.078s
```

Is stdout/print() unbuffered by default in Dart? Is there something like java's PrintWriter? thanks. (**Update: after warming up vm, stdout is 2x slower than java** )

```
real 0m15.497s   
user 0m0.046s   
sys 0m0.047s
```

===============================================================================

**Update Sep 30, 2013**

I have implemented custom buffers for both dart and java codes to make a further comparing,now the result is as follows:

```
//test.dart
final int SIZE = 8192;
final int NUM = 1 << 25;
void main(){
  List<int> content = new List(SIZE);
  content.fillRange(0, SIZE, 0);
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM;i++){
    if(i % SIZE == 0 && i > 0)
        print(content);
    content[i % SIZE] = i;
  }
  if (NUM % SIZE ==0)
    print(content);
  else
    print(content.sublist(0, NUM % SIZE));
}
```

java version:

```
//Test.java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test{
public static final int SIZE = 8192;
public static final int NUM = 1 << 25;
public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
    try{
        int[] buf = new int[SIZE];
        for(int i = 0;i < NUM; i++){
            if(i % SIZE == 0 && i > 0)
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(buf));
            buf[i % SIZE] = i;              
        }
        if(NUM % SIZE == 0)
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(buf));
        else
        {
            int[] newbuf = new int[NUM % SIZE];
            newbuf = Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 0, (NUM % SIZE));
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(newbuf));
        }
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

$ time java Test > /dev/null

```
real    0m7.397s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.031s
```

$ time dart test.dart > /dev/null

```
real    0m22.406s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.062s
```

As you see, dart is still 3x slower than java.

Comment: An [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788467/console-print-speed) to a similar question seems to get a bit faster speeds: 2x slower vs. 3x slower. Perhaps it might help you optimize a bit further.

Comment: @PixelElephant: Thanks for your reply.I have read the answer and tried to directly write output into a file instead of printing on console but it is still 3x slower than java. Maybe the internal dart VM or something else need be more optimized.

Comment: Now in 2018, with Dart VM 2.0.0 dev 62 the respective times are 1. **Dart**: 5.145s, 2. **Java** : 3.686s, on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code does not get optimized by the VM.
Only "frequenly" used functions are compiled and executed as native code.
Usually for such benchmark, you have to put the tested code into a function and perform a warmup. For exemple:

```
//test.dart
import 'dart:io';
void f(nb_shift) {
for(int i = 0; i < 1 << nb_shift;i++){
   stdout.write(i); // or directly print(i);
 }
}

void main(){
  //warm up:
  f(3);
  // the test
  f(25);
  stdout.close();
}
```

Nicolas

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really helpful.After warming up,now stdout is 2x slower than java.